# Python break statement within try except block

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to put a `break` statement within `try` and `except` block, I want to print the Message `Invalid interface on the host123.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0

import sys
import re
import socket
import os

system_name = socket.gethostname()

def usage():
        print '''USAGE: %s [options] [bond_interface]

Options:
        --help, -h      This usage document

Arguments:
        bond_interface  The bonding interface to query, eg. 'bond0'. Default is 'bond0'.
''' % (sys.argv[0])
        sys.exit(1)

# Parse arguments
try:
        iface = sys.argv[1]
        if iface in ('--help', '-h'):
                usage()
except IndexError:
        iface = 'bond0'

# Grab the inf0z from /proc
try:
        bond = open("/proc/net/bonding/%s" % iface).read()

except IOError:
        print "ERROR: Invalid interface %s %s\n" % (iface, system_name)
        usage()
```

I tried to put the if condition as follows but gives `SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop`.

```
# Grab the inf0z from /proc
try:
        bond = open("/proc/net/bonding/%s" % iface).read()
        if not os.path.exists("bond"):
            break
except IOError:
        print "ERROR: Invalid interface %s %s\n" % (iface, system_name)
        usage()
```

However print statement works but also prints help section which i want to stop

```
ERROR: Invalid interface apc4502.nxdi.nl-cdc01.nxp.com bond0

USAGE:  [options] [bond_interface]

Options:
        --help, -h      This usage document

Arguments:
        bond_interface  The bonding interface to query, eg. 'bond0'. Default is 'bond0'.
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `break` is only meaningful inside a loop. You don't have any loops.

Comment: Are you trying to end the program?

Comment: `except IOError: print "ERROR: Invalid interface %s %s\n" % (iface, system_name)` doesn't this print what you want?

Comment: What was your point? Using breaks inside try...except blocks is not making sense. You should revize your algorithm.

Comment: @Ahmet, yes it prints but it also prints the help section.

Comment: Remove the help section?

Comment: Yes but only for Error one.

Comment: @BrendenPrice, no i don't want to end the program.

Comment: The only way to "exit" the `try` block is to raise an exception or to complete the `try` block. `break` would "complete" the `try` block if the `try` statement itself were inside a loop.

Comment: That said, use `argparse` to parse your arguments rather than doing it by hand.

Comment: @chepner, thank i am not an expert just trying to learn that's why just trying to see how it can be modulated best way. thanks for the advise.

Comment: @Barmar, thank you for the insightful suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Use `argparse` to parse your command-line arguments.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0

import sys
import socket
import os

import argparse

p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('bond_interface', default='bond0')
args = p.parse_args()

system_name = socket.gethostname()

bond_name = os.path.join("/proc/net/bonding", args.bond_interface)

try:
    with open(bond_name) as f:
        bond =  f.read()
except IOError:
    print(f"ERROR: Problem reading from {bond_name} on {system_name}", file=sys.stderr)
```

Comment: Many thanks chepner for keeping the solution, this `f'string` we can only use in python3 ? i am using python2.7 for some reason. +1 already.

Comment: The question was tagged `python-3.x`; you can adjust the `print` statement or call to the `print` function as necessary.

Comment: Thank you chepner.

Comment: i see a problem using this `usage: [-h] bond_interface: error: too few arguments`

Comment: You can still specify a custom usage message, via the `usage` keyword argument to `ArgumentParser`.